# How XMPP transfer messages between two different servers(of different domains) without any intermediate hops?

Tags: networking, server, xmpp

My team wants to build a chat app and so we are researching about all the available technologies available at our arsenal. I am concerned about XMPP. So i was reading the Oreilly's "XMPP: The definitive guide", and came across these lines and i quote

`In XMPP, messages are delivered as fast as possible over the network. Let’s say that Alice sends a message from her new account on the wonderland.lit server to her sister on the realworld.lit server. Her client effectively “uploads” the message to wonderland.lit by pushing a message stanza over a client-to-server XML stream. The wonderland.lit server then stamps a from address on the stanza and checks the to ad- dress in order to see how the stanza needs to be handled (without performing any deep packet inspection or XML parsing, since that would eat into the delivery time). Seeing that the message stanza is bound for the realworld.lit server, the wonderland.lit server then immediately routes the message to realworld.lit over a server-to-server XML stream (with no intermediate hops).`Page 45

`Like email, but unlike the Web, XMPP systems involve a great deal of inter-domain connections. However, when you send an XMPP message to one of your contacts at a different domain, your client connects to your “home” server, which then connects directly to your contact’s server without intermediate hops (see Figure 2-4).`Page 13

Can anyone please make me understand how can there be no intermediate hops(unlike email).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E-Mail (SMTP) also has no intermediate hops. I assume you confuse the application OSI layer, where XMPP, SMTP and so on live, with the network layer (IP).

Comment: Ok so after reading rfc5321(https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-3.6), there are relay servers which are responsible for sending email (using mx dns records). That is alright. But still the doubt is how in xmpp does it happen(without any intermediate hops). For eg. i am sending message from c1@s1.org to c2@s2.org, how does s1 know to send message to s2(is there any dns record for this too, i dont think so). Can you please elaborate in detail, it would be really helpful!!!

Comment: On the contrary, there is exactly such a DNS record. See [RFC 6120 3.2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6120#section-3.2.1).